# Manjaro doesn't recognize USB mouse movement

Tags: manjaro, mouse, usb-device

the trackpad works perfectly fine but no USB mouse I tried works. I can see the mouse is detected in lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 248a:8366 Maxxter Wireless Optical Mouse ACT-MUSW-002
```

and inxi -Jxxx shows

```
Hub-3: 3-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 4 rev: 2.0
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
Device-1: 3-2:5 info: Maxxter Wireless Optical Mouse ACT-MUSW-002
  type: Mouse driver: N/A interfaces: 1 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s power: 50mA
  chip-ID: 248a:8366 class-ID: 0301
```

but no movement is detected even using libinput debug-events. I tried another USB mouse I had (this one was wired) and saw similar results. also I checked both mice with a windows machine to confirm they're not broken.
what can I do to get the mouse to work?

Answer (score 0):

The driver module for most USB mice is `usbhid`. Some rare USB mice might support the *USB HID boot protocol* only; for those, the required driver module is `usbmouse`. The standard kernel source code includes both these drivers.

To verify that your kernel configuration includes these drivers, run:

```
grep -e CONFIG_USB_HID -e CONFIG_USB_MOUSE /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

Or if your distribution does not have the kernel configuration file at `/boot/config-*` but has `/proc/config.gz`, then run:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -e CONFIG_USB_HID -e CONFIG_USB_MOUSE
```

A typical response should be similar to:

```
CONFIG_USB_HID=m
CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV=y
CONFIG_USB_MOUSE=m
```

If the setting for `CONFIG_USB_HID` or `CONFIG_USB_MOUSE` is `y`, it means the driver is built-in to the current kernel and should be always in use. If the setting is `m`, it means the driver is built as a module, and you could try loading it with `modprobe usbhid` or `modprobe usbmouse`, respectively.

Normally, most distributions should automatically load the USB mouse driver as soon as an USB mouse is plugged in, if the driver is built as a module. In your case the driver was clearly not loaded: if `modprobe usbhid` or `modprobe usbmouse` makes the mouse start working, you would have to investigate why the automatic driver loading failed. Are there any related error messages in the system logs, or has the module been blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/`?

If the results include a line like:

```
# CONFIG_USB_HID is not set
```

or

```
# CONFIG_USB_MOUSE is not set
```

then the respective driver was disabled in your current kernel configuration; you would have to change your kernel configuration and build a new version of the kernel to enable it (or switch to using a kernel that already has those drivers enabled).

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. when I run the command you said I just get
grep: /boot/config-5.15.48-1-MANJARO: No such file or directory
if I'm not mistaken the location you mentioned is for debian-based linux distros but I can't find the appropriate info in /proc/config.gz which is (as far as my search turned up) the location for arch-based distros

Comment: Having the kernel configuration file in `/boot` is - or at least used to be - the norm not only in Debian, but in RedHat and SuSE too. But `/proc/config.gz` is just as good. As the name indicates, it is gzipped. Try `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -e CONFIG_USB_HID -e CONFIG_USB_MOUSE`.

Comment: trying the command you said it gives me the correct settings for usbhid but nothing for usbmouse. how can I install it. also after rebooting the computer with the mouse plugged in the mouse started working. but I'd like to make sure it works correctly with all mice